# Replace original rows with duplicate rows then remove duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to

```
    Name   Value  Value2
     A       1      11        
     B       2      12
     C       3      13
     A       4      14
     B       5      15
```

I need to take the rows were Name is a duplicate and replace the rows with the first occurrence with the last occurrence and then remove the last duplicates. So in this example the output would be

```
    Name   Value  Value2
     A       4      14
     B       5      15
     C       3      13
```

What would be a efficient way of doing this?

Comment: please,check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```py
data.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last').sort_values('Name')
```

Comment: No because it won't replace the index. the output of that would be something like C,A,B correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes because you can sort by `'Name'` after the fact. `data.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last').sort_values('Name')`

Comment: Yes, you can just sort it if need be. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
df = df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).nth(-1)
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).nth(-1)`

Comment: You are moving the `'Name'` column to the index.  You can keep in the dataframe proper by passing the argument `as_index=False`.  Also, no need to pass `[-1]` when `-1` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [groupby.last](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).last()
```

Output:

```
  Name  Value  Value2
0    A      4      14
1    B      5      15
2    C      3      13
```

Comment: Similar to what I wrote for [bimarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58344562/2336654) you can preempt the need for a `reset_index` with a `as_index=False` argument in the `groupby` call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep the last occurence of each individual `Name` value, you wouldn't care of replacing the earlier ones. You should just drop duplicates, filtered by `Name` and pass the parameter `keep='last'`:

```
data = {'Name':['A','B','C','A','B'],'Value':[1,2,3,4,5],'Value2':[11,12,13,14,15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop_duplicates('Name',keep='last')
print(DataFrame)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Value  Value2
2    C      3      13
3    A      4      14
4    B      5      15
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [EAB's answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58344539/2336654)

Comment: My bad, I did not see it.